# Constitution mobile Application-Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, jquery-mobile

I am building a Constitution Mobile Application (Android) for my group. I want to seek ideas as to how to choose the appropriate method which will in a long way help my group and its users.

I want to know which of the following is the best

1. Creating static pages (constitution) on the mobile App - However this method will be bound to be unchanged even if there is a spelling mistake. It can only be changed when there is a new release of a different version of the App.
2. Creating a database which will sync data (Constitution content) from the remote mysql/php server.

These are the two methods that comes in mind. Please if there is any best solution to my problem, I would be grateful to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to make the server calls in Android, and if the database is going to be relatively simple to set up, I would recommend fetching the Constitution data to display in an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Otherwise, might as well just be extra careful with the initial release of the App and go with the static pages. Would most likely save a ton of time.

Comment: There is a suggestion that I should create a database, insert all the data and then add it to the resource file. So my database will be installed at the time of the app installation. What do u think? Is that way ok. Wat is the standard? Thanks.